# Reduse integer everytime an new object is added to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, addition, subtraction

I have a class of Person with an ArrayList of the class Groceries. 
Let's name the Arraylist `shoppingBag`.

Student and Groceries has one field each, `int money` and `int price`.
The specific amount of money and price is up to you when initializing new objects.

So every time a Person adds an object of Groceries to his shoppingBag, the amount of money he has needs to be reduced with the total price of groceries added to the bag.

How do you do that?

Comment: _How do you do that?_ How did you do that? Show us your code..

Answer (score 1):

So, let my try to understand what you want (as I do the same for my clients)

You have a class Groceries with price field:

```
class Groceries {
    private int price;

    public Groceries(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Groceries{" +
                "price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And class person with int money filed and shopping bag field as List of Groceries:

```
class Person {

    private List<Groceries> shoppingBag = new ArrayList<>();
    private int money;

    public Person(int money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public List<Groceries> getShoppingBag() {
        return shoppingBag;
    }

    public int getMoney() {
        return money;
    }
}
```

Firstly you create an instance of `Person` with some mount of money: `Person person = new Person(150);`

And then each time when you add a groceries to the shopping bag, like `person.getShoppingBag().add(new Groceries(10));` you do want to reduce amount of money from the person instance.

So, If I am correct, you need to implement several things:

1) You should forbid adding groceries to the shopping bag with the way described before. We need to throw an exception when someone tries to add an element to the List via getter. It can be implemented using an Unmodifiable copy of your list:

```
public List<Groceries> getShoppingBag() {
    List<Groceries> bag = new UnmodifiableArrayList<>(shoppingBag.toArray(new Groceries[shoppingBag.size()]), shoppingBag.size());
    return bag;
}
```

or a little bit nicely and shortly using Guava:

```
public List<Groceries> getShoppingBag() {
    List<Groceries> bag = ImmutableList.copyOf(shoppingBag);
    return bag;
}
```

2) Add a method that will add a groceries directly. You can also throw an exception if there is no enough money to not have negative balance:

```
public void addToShoppingBag(Groceries groceries) {

    if (0 > money - groceries.getPrice()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You have not enough money!");
    }

    shoppingBag.add(groceries);
    money -= groceries.getPrice();
}
```

3) Probably you will need to have possibility to add some money:

```
private void addMoney(int amout) {
    money += amout;
}
```

Please see the completely demo example:

```
class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Person person = new Person(42);
        try {
            System.out.println(person.getMoney());
            person.addToShoppingBag(new Groceries(12));
            person.addToShoppingBag(new Groceries(20));
            person.addToShoppingBag(new Groceries(5));
            System.out.println(person.getMoney());
            System.out.println(person.getShoppingBag());
            person.getShoppingBag().add(new Groceries(1));
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            person.addToShoppingBag(new Groceries(66));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class Person {

    private List<Groceries> shoppingBag = new ArrayList<>();
    private int money;

    public Person(int money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public List<Groceries> getShoppingBag() {
        List<Groceries> bag = ImmutableList.copyOf(shoppingBag);
        return bag;
    }

    public void addToShoppingBag(Groceries groceries) {

        if (0 > money - groceries.getPrice()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You have not enough money!");
        }

        shoppingBag.add(groceries);
        money -= groceries.getPrice();
    }

    private void addMoney(int amout) {
        money += amout;
    }

    public int getMoney() {
        return money;
    }
}

class Groceries {
    private int price;

    public Groceries(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Groceries{" +
                "price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

PS: Please next time describe some examples of code and demos to get an answer :)